# add srdf file to gazebo empty_world

Tags: ros, srdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to simply load a srdf file to Gazebo instead of an URDF file. I followed a simple [Gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch#UsingroslaunchtoSpawnURDFRobots) that instructs me on how to launch an URDF file using the following commands:

Terminal 1:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

Terminal 2:

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find robot_pkg`/urdf/MYROBOT.urdf -urdf -model MYROBOT
```

This spawns the robot in Gazebo but not without fidgeting completely (possibly due to self-collisions) and jumping 1000 ft in the air. So I am trying to load a SRDF file instead with the following commands:

Terminal 1:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

Terminal 2:

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file `rospack find robot_config`/config/MYROBOT.srdf -sdf -model MYROBOT
```

When I hit enter on Terminal 2, the following occurs:

```
SpawnModel script started
[INFO] [1503422995.443726, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from file
[INFO] [1503422995.444003, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_sdf_model
[INFO] [1503422995.444960, 0.000000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_sdf_model
[INFO] [1503423005.472383, 16.663000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Entity pushed to spawn queue, but spawn service timed out waiting for entity to appear in simulation under the name kr500
```

Then Terminal 1 reads

```
Error:   No link elements found in urdf file
     at line 180 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:3408] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:340] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
```

What doesn't make sense is why the tutorial tells me I should be able to **simply load up a SRDF file**. I looked over the parameters to run on the terminal and they appear correct. Only terminal 1 should be calling parseSDF not parseURDF. Maybe this is my problem. But I'm not instructed on what commands to run so any **further knowledge on the command to load a SDF file** would be helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269357/add-srdf-file-to-gazebo-empty_world/) by [maxgitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/30480/maxgitt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`.srdf` != `.sdf`.

`srdf` files are MoveIt Robot Semantic Description files. `sdf` is Gazebo's Simulation Description Format.

Those are not related and you cannot load an `srdf` file in Gazebo.

> What doesn't make sense is why the tutorial tells me I should be able to **simply load up a SRDF file**

I don't believe it actually tells you that SRDF is supported.

> This spawns the robot in Gazebo but not without fidgeting completely (possibly due to self-collisions) and jumping 1000 ft in the air.

One thing to check is that you have your robot linked to the `world` frame using a `fixed` joint.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxgitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/30480/maxgitt/) on 2017-08-22**:
Adding the world frame helped me take a step towards a more stable robot. But I'll be attempting to fix other joints that are misbehaving

**Comment by [nknight](https://answers.ros.org/users/50581/nknight/) on 2019-12-30**:
Hi @maxgiit have you found the solution yet, i face the same problem as you :(